# pyspark opens inside Jupyter notebook and not shell

Tags: python, bash, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I had specified some export commands in my `.bash_profile` which force pyspark to open the jupyter notebook. Now I have deleted all those export commands, but I still get pyspark as jupyter notebook window and not inside a terminal. My `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=edb0b30ce31ccda5b3f4f1229641d381efab30e4
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/sparker0i/binary/spark
export SBT_HOME=/Users/sparker0i/binary/sbt
export SCALA_HOME=/Users/sparker0i/binary/scala
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/sparker0i/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH
```

When I do `source .bash_profile` no changes happen. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why not just get info > opens with... > change all

Comment: Get info on what?

Comment: On your pyspark file or whatever it is...

Comment: I'm not interested to go all the way to that location in Finder and then open from there. I want it to do right from my terminal.